# Using values of dataframe column as JSON Keys

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, indexing, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe with 6 columns that I am trying to convert to JSON in a desired format. What I've been having trouble with is using the actual values of a column in my dataframe as keys in my JSON.

Here is an example of a dataframe

```py
ogdf = pd.DataFrame({'country': ["USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA","USA"],
                   'scenario': ["actual", "target","actual", "target","actual", "target","actual", "target","actual", "target","actual", "target"],
                   'currency': ["USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","USD","USD"],
                   'period': ['1998 1Q', '2000', '2001-12','1998 1Q', '2000', '2001-12','1998 1Q', '2000', '2001-12','1998 1Q', '2000', '2001-12'],
                   'account': ['SALES 1','SALES 2','SALES 3','SALES 4','SALES 5','SALES 6','SALES 7','SALES 8','SALES 9','SALES 10','SALES 11','SALES 12'],
                   'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31,55, 40, 84, 31,55, 40, 84, 31]})
```

and with this piece of code

```
grouped_data = (ogdf.groupby(['country', 'scenario', 'currency'])
    .apply(lambda x: x[['account', 'sale']].to_dict(orient='records'))
    .reset_index()
    .to_dict(orient='records'))
```

I was able to get the following result

```
[
  {
    "country": "USA",
    "scenario": "actual",
    "currency": "USD",
    "0": [
      {
        "account": "SALES 1",
        "sale": 55
      },
      {
        "account": "SALES 3",
        "sale": 84
      },
      {
        "account": "SALES 5",
        "sale": 55
      }
```

So instead of the key "0" I wish to have the values of column "period" so that it shows al the accounts and sales for that period

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the same thing for `('period', ['account', 'sale'])`

```
grouped_data = (ogdf.groupby(['country', 'scenario', 'currency'])
                    .apply(lambda x: x.groupby('period')[['account', 'sale']]
                                      .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records')))
                    .reset_index().to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Output:

```
>>> grouped_data
[{'country': 'USA',
  'scenario': 'actual',
  'currency': 'USD',
  '1998 1Q': [{'account': 'SALES 1', 'sale': 55},
   {'account': 'SALES 7', 'sale': 84}],
  '2000': [{'account': 'SALES 5', 'sale': 55},
   {'account': 'SALES 11', 'sale': 84}],
  '2001-12': [{'account': 'SALES 3', 'sale': 84},
   {'account': 'SALES 9', 'sale': 55}]},
 {'country': 'USA',
  'scenario': 'target',
  'currency': 'USD',
  '1998 1Q': [{'account': 'SALES 4', 'sale': 31},
   {'account': 'SALES 10', 'sale': 40}],
  '2000': [{'account': 'SALES 2', 'sale': 40},
   {'account': 'SALES 8', 'sale': 31}],
  '2001-12': [{'account': 'SALES 6', 'sale': 40},
   {'account': 'SALES 12', 'sale': 31}]}]
```

JSON output:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(grouped_data, indent=4))

# Output
[
    {
        "country": "USA",
        "scenario": "actual",
        "currency": "USD",
        "1998 1Q": [
            {
                "account": "SALES 1",
                "sale": 55
            },
            {
                "account": "SALES 7",
                "sale": 84
            }
        ],
        "2000": [
            {
                "account": "SALES 5",
                "sale": 55
            },
            {
                "account": "SALES 11",
                "sale": 84
            }
        ],
        "2001-12": [
            {
                "account": "SALES 3",
                "sale": 84
            },
            {
                "account": "SALES 9",
                "sale": 55
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country": "USA",
        "scenario": "target",
        "currency": "USD",
        "1998 1Q": [
            {
                "account": "SALES 4",
                "sale": 31
            },
            {
                "account": "SALES 10",
                "sale": 40
            }
        ],
        "2000": [
            {
                "account": "SALES 2",
                "sale": 40
            },
            {
                "account": "SALES 8",
                "sale": 31
            }
        ],
        "2001-12": [
            {
                "account": "SALES 6",
                "sale": 40
            },
            {
                "account": "SALES 12",
                "sale": 31
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I accepted your solution because it works for the example I provided! but originally, in my currency column, I have 2 distinct values not one like in the example I provided, and that is oddly causing your solution not to work. What modification would you make?

Comment: @berking11 not work how? In that case, consider posting a follow-up question with adapted input data